# How can I copy a vector to another location and reuse the existing allocated memory?

Tags: vector, rust, copy, clone

In C++, to copy the contents of a vector to another vector we use the assignment operator `dest = src`. However, in Rust `src` would be moved into `dest` and no longer usable.

I know the simplest answer is to do `dest = src.clone()` (for the sake of this question we'll assume `T` in `Vec<T>` is `Clone`). However - if I'm understanding correctly - this creates a brand new third vector with the copied contents of `src` and moves it into `dest`, throwing away `dest`'s dynamically allocated array. If this is correct, it's a completely unnecessary dynamic allocation when we could have just copied the content directly into `dest` (assuming it had sufficient capacity).

Below is a function I've made that does exactly what I would like to do: empty out the `dest` vector and copy the elements of `src` to it.

```rust
// copy contents of src to dest without just cloning src
fn copy_content<T: Clone>(dest: &mut Vec<T>, src: &Vec<T>) {
    dest.clear();
    if dest.capacity() < src.len() {
        dest.reserve(src.len());
    }
    for x in src {
        dest.push(x.clone());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with builtin or standard library utilities? Is the `dest = src.clone()` optimized by the compiler to do this anyway?

I know that if `T` has dynamic resources then the extra allocation from `src.clone()` isn't a big deal, but if `T` is e.g. `i32` or any other `Copy` type then it forces an allocation where none are necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you ever look at the [definition of `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)? It has the well known `clone` method but also a useful but often forgotten [`clone_from` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#method.clone_from):

```rust
pub trait Clone : Sized {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self;
    fn clone_from(&mut self, source: &Self) {
        *self = source.clone()
    }
}
```

To quote the doc:

> Performs copy-assignment from source.
>
> `a.clone_from(&b)` is equivalent to `a = b.clone()` in functionality, but can be overridden to reuse the resources of `a` to avoid unnecessary allocations.

Of course [a type such as `Vec` does not use the provided-by-default `clone_from` and defines](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/bc1571cc3cfef07251f7df52b95525aa16797ca2/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1855-L1857) its own in a more efficient way, similar to what you would get in C++ from writing `dest = src`:

```rust
fn clone_from(&mut self, other: &Vec<T>) {
    other.as_slice().clone_into(self);
}
```

with [`[T]::clone_into` being defined as](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3a087ad3a924be12343bb035bf9b63ed81f650bf/src/liballoc/slice.rs#L735-L746):

```rust
fn clone_into(&self, target: &mut Vec<T>) {
    // drop anything in target that will not be overwritten
    target.truncate(self.len());
    let len = target.len();

    // reuse the contained values' allocations/resources.
    target.clone_from_slice(&self[..len]);

    // target.len <= self.len due to the truncate above, so the
    // slice here is always in-bounds.
    target.extend_from_slice(&self[len..]);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea that was part of `Clone`. I've just been going through the Rust book tutorial thing and they never mentioned it... That's perfect!

Comment: It is worth noting that while `clone_from` is defined in trait `Clone`, `clone_into` actually belongs to trait [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#method.clone_into).

Comment: @rodrigo Right but for now `clone_into` is not stable. I only included it in the answer to show that it does indeed reuse memory.