# How to replace the content of a String variable after it has been created?

Tags: string, rust

I found two different ways to do it; but as a code reader, neither of them clearly describes what we want to do (simply setting the string content); I would have expected something like `s.set("hello")`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hi");
    s.clear();
    s.push_str("hello");
    println!("{}", s);

    let mut s = String::from("hi");
    s.replace_range(.., "hello");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Is there a more readable way to do it? It is such a straightforward task that I'm surprised there is no shortcut method for it.

My goal is to keep as much efficiency as possible. I'd like to keep the actual capacity if possible, copy the new string content into the existent allocated zone and update the string size.

Comment: also a rust noobie here, what is wrong with doing `s = String::from("something else");`?

Comment: @khuynh that would allocate a new piece of memory for the new `String`, then throw away the memory for the old; it's potentially less efficient (but worrying about that efficiency is not always worth it).

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually, to learn more about this language I want to learn. The naive goal was to define a "setter" like in other languages, with proto `set_text(&mut self, text: &str)` for the `text: String` property of a custom struct

Comment: *Is there a simpler way to do it?* — what would you like to see simpler about `s.replace_range(.., "hello");`?

Comment: I wrote it at the beginning: something more meaningful like `s.set("hello")`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"neither of them seem to be really adapted"_ -- I'm not sure what "adapted" means in that sentence.

Comment: @PeterHall Please see my edit (edited the intro + the question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [`String::replace_range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s: String = String::from("alpha");
    println!("{}", s);

    s.replace_range(.., "beta");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

If you truly dislike this, you can create an *extension trait*:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s: String = String::from("alpha");
    println!("{}", s);

    s.set("beta");
    println!("{}", s);
}

trait StringSetExt {
    fn set(&mut self, s: &str);
}

impl StringSetExt for String {
    fn set(&mut self, s: &str) {
        self.replace_range(.., s);
    }
}
```

---

> It is such a straightforward task that I'm surprised there is no shortcut method for it.

I honestly don't think I've *ever* seen anyone want to do this in the ~5 years I've been doing Rust, and I think it's rarely worth it from a performance point of view.

Instead, I think it's more likely that the caller has already allocated some memory that they don't care about. In that case, I'd accept the string from them:

```
struct Person(String);

impl Person {
    fn set_name(&mut self, s: impl Into<String>) {
        self.0 = s.into();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Person(String::new());
    p.set_name("alpha");
    p.set_name(String::from("beta"));
}
```

See also:

- [How can I copy a vector to another location and reuse the existing allocated memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59604714/155423)

Comment: Thank you, your edit is clearly the actual answer I needed.